# NextJS Router doesn't reload data until page refocus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query, next-router

Currently working with NextJS, but struggling to make an indexing page of sorts. With the router, I'm trying to get the page number by doing this:

```js
let router = useRouter()
let page = isNaN(router.query.page) ? 1 : parseInt(router.query.page);
```

So that when I go to page=1, page=2 etc, I get new sets of data.
The functionality for this is called in the same main component, and is a React Query function:

```js
const {data, status} = useQuery(["keycaps", {manu: manuId}, {prof: profileId}, {col: colorId}, {stat: statusId}], getKeycaps)
```

And said function looks like this:

```js
const getKeycaps = async(key) => {
    const manuId = key.queryKey[1].manu
    const profileIds = key.queryKey[2].prof.map(id => `profile.id=${id}`)
    const colorIds = key.queryKey[3].col.map(id => `filter_colors.id=${id}`)
    const statId = key.queryKey[4].stat

    const profileQueryString = profileIds.join("&")
    const colorQueryString = colorIds.join("&")

    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    let page = urlParams.get("page") == null ? 1 : parseInt(urlParams.get("page"));

    let start = (page * 10) - 10

    const data = await axios(`
        ${process.env.REACT_APP_STRAPI_API}/keycaps?${manuId ? 'manufacturer.id=' + manuId + '&' : ''}${profileQueryString ? profileQueryString + '&' : ''}${colorQueryString ? colorQueryString + '&' : ''}_start=${start}&_limit=10`)
    return data.data
}
```

When initially loading pages, like directly pasting the url of the index in (i.e. keycaps?page=2), it will get all the results all fine. However, if I start using navigational buttons like this:

```
<Link href={`/keycaps?page=${page - 1}`}> // next/link
    <div className="w-32 rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
        Prev
    </div>
</Link>
<Link href={`/keycaps?page=${page + 1}`}>
    <div className="w-32 rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
        Next
    </div>
</Link>
```

The whole thing starts to break down. Essentially, the page doesn't actually reload any data or results until the page is unfocused. So, if I press the Next button to go to the next page, it won't load the data until I do something like tab to a new window or check a different internet tab, and then when I come back, the data will all magically load within a second.
I've tried this with next build && next start too, and this produces the same results. I just want to get the page results when the next and prev page buttons are pressed, and in a way that doesn't require the user to switch tabs to get content.

I will note that I do have a `getStaticProps` on this as well. It does the following:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const allKeycaps = (await getAllKeycaps() || 'Error')
    return {
        props: { allKeycaps }
    }
}
```

Which will call an api script, and said script does this:

```js
async function fetchAPI(query, {variables} = {}) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRAPI_API}/graphql`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query,
            variables,
        }),
    })

    const json = await res.json()
    
    if (json.errors) {
        console.error(json.errors)
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
    }

    console.log('json', json.data, variables)

    return json.data
}
/* Keycap related grabs */

export async function getAllKeycaps() {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
        `
        {
            keycaps {
                id
                slug
                name
                published_at
                updatedAt
                profile {
                    id
                    name
                }
                manufacturer {
                    id
                    name
                    lead
                }
                status {
                    id
                    name
                }
                colors
                filter_colors {
                    color
                }
                kits
                designer
                thumb {
                    formats
                }
            }
        }
        `
    )
    return data
}
```

Anyone know how to get this to work? To navigate between indexes like this? I've been trying to look for Next tutorials that use navigations like page 1, page 2 etc but all I can find is examples of blog articles with slugs, no index searches of any kind.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found:

When setting data and status using useQuery

```js
const curPage = router.query.page == null ? 1 : router.query.page

const {data, status} = useQuery(["keycaps", {manu: manuId}, {prof: profileId}, {col: colorId}, {stat: statusId}, {page: curPage}], getKeycaps)
```

And then, in getKeycaps

```js
const page = key.queryKey[5].page
```

I guess the "urlParams" approach wasn't a good one? Or at least, not one that was updating quick enough. So passing through the router page number seems to work better.